# How do I display the two different records in one single row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have searched on the stackoverflow, but I didn't find any question mentioning to merge two records in single row based on different date.

I have this table.

```
ID    Timestamp            State
6      2016-02-03 07:13      End
5      2016-02-02 21:09      Start
4      2016-02-02 9:10       End
3      2016-02-01 21:10      Start
2      2016-02-01 6:30       End
1      2016-01-31 23:40      Start
```

So process 'A' is starting at `2016-01-31 23:40` and getting stopped at `2016-02-01 6:30`, and so on. I want to display it in this way:

```
Start Time        End Time
2016-01-31 23:40  2016-02-01 6:30
2016-02-01 21:10  2016-02-02 9:10
2016-02-02 21:09  2016-02-03 07:13
```

There are other records between `Start` and `End` tags.
Can you tell me how to go solve it? I am trying to get the solution on the WAMP server.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?  Please tag the question appropriately.  I am removing both these tags, so you can add the appropriate one.

Comment: Any id or sequence column?

Comment: @jarlh Yes there is id for each record. I thought that the id will be of no use, as there are other records between each pair of `start` and `end`. Or do you think still that I should add the id column?

Comment: An identifying column would be required to know which lines belong together. The identifier should be the same for each pair of lines. An auto-increment field will not do in this case. You *could* achieve what you want if you can make the assumption that the next "end" with a timestamp greater than a start belongs to that start (no overlapping timespans).

Comment: How do you know which end corresponds with each start? Or can you just have one running process at the time?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Each record has its unique id. I am adding the id column for better understanding.

Comment: If each record has a *unique* id, how would you match the two records that belong together? You could create an additional column that stores the id of the start record for each end record. Then matching is easy.

Comment: @Tobb There is only one process. It starts and gets end, again it starts and end, and so on.

Comment: It doesn't matter that there are records with other states. They have no meaning for the given problem, so we simply don't read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If less query, and better performance is your thing...

```
SELECT x.timestamp start
     , MIN(y.timestamp) end 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.timestamp > x.timestamp 
   AND y.state = 'end' 
 WHERE x.state = 'start' 
 GROUP 
    BY x.timestamp;
```

Comment: This can produce a huge intermediate result, though. I guess from a performance point of view one should use the row number technique: number all starts and all ends and match on row number then.

Answer (score 2):

If the ID has no gaps, you could just use a self-join on id <=> id+1, but it is usually a bad idea to rely on such things with technical IDs. You could do about the same by giving row numbers to all starts and all ends and join on these. Or you use a simple subselect in your where clause:

```
select 
  timestamp as start_time,
  (
    select min(timestamp)
    from mytable ends
    where ends.state = 'End'
    and ends.timestamp > starts.timestamp
  ) as end_time
from mytable starts
where state = 'Start'
order by timestamp;
```